# Cron job Django Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, cron, cron-task

I am trying to set a cron job on my project to send a email after 15 minutes.

This is in django.config

```
04_cronjb:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/cron-linux.config > /etc/cron.d/crontab && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/crontab"
    leader_only: true
```

This is my cron-linux.config file

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            

            * * * * * source /opt/python/current/env && python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py cronjb
```

It all deploys successfully but i am not receiving any email.
Cronjb script is working i have tested it. So the error is one these two files.
Is there some mistake in it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `04_cronjb` copies entire content of `cron-linux.config` into `crontab`. This is sadly incorrect.

Instead you should do as shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/). This includes putting all the bash commands you want to execute in a custom script called, e.g., `myscript.sh` and then adding `myscript.sh` to cron only.